# Is it possible to select an element from each of these sets that meet these criteria?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I apologize for the vague title, but I can't think of a more succinct way to put it given the specificity of the question.

Say we have nine sets, which are as follows:

$$ S_1=\{A1, A2, A3, C2\} 
\\
S_2=\{A1, C1\}
\\
S_3=\{B2\}
\\
S_4=\{B3, C1, C2, C3\}
\\
S_5=\{A2, C2\}
\\
S_6=\{A1, A3, B1\}
\\
S_7=\{A1, A3, B1\}
\\
S_8=\{A3, B1, C3\}
\\
S_9=\{C1, C3\}$$

We then pick a single element from each set and put it into a new set, $T$. An element from $S_n$ becomes the element $t_n$ in $T$.

Here are our restrictions:

- In each group of three (that is: for $t_1, t_2,\text{ and }t_3$; $t_4, t_5,\text{ and }t_6$; and $t_7, t_8,\text{ and }t_9$), the letters associated with each element must be different. For example, you cannot have $t_1=A2$ and $t_2=A1$. There *must* be an $A, B$, and $C$ in each group of three.
- For every element $t_n$, the numbers associated with $t_{(n\mod3)\ +\ 3k\ +\ 1}$ for $k=0,1,2$ must be different. For example, you cannot have $t_1=A1$ and $t_4=C1$. There *must* be a $1, 2,$ and $3$ present in each subset like this.
- There can be no repeat elements in the list.
- Within each aforementioned group of three, the letters for $t_n$ and $t_{n+1}$ cannot be adjacent if their numbers are the same. For example, you cannot have $t_7=A1$ and $t_8=B1$. (For the sake of clarity - $A$ is considered adjacent to $B$ and $B$ to $C$, but $A$ is *not* adjacent to $C$.)
- You cannot have adjacent numbers for $t_n$ and $t_{n+3}$ if the letters are the same. For example, you cannot have $t_5=C2$ and $t_8=C3$.

With these restrictions, does $T$ exist? I've been trying stuff here and there for a few hours, and I have something that fulfills all restrictions except for the final one - $T=\{A2, \textbf{C1}, B2, B3, \textbf{C2}, A1, B1, A3, C3\}$ - but I just can't seem to get them all to fit. Any leads? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering this for some time, I realized: no. Clearly not.

The reason is simple. $t_4$ *must* be $B3$ by virtue of the pigeonhole principle - there are a total of nine discrete elements and nine spaces to fill, and $B3$ only appears in $S_4$. From here, the problem unravels itself.

First, since we know that $B3$ is the only element of $S_4$ we care about, let's do some tidying up:

$$ S_1=\{A2\} 
\\
S_2=\{C1\}
\\
S_3=\{B2\}
\\
S_4=\{B3\}
\\
S_5=\{C2\}
\\
S_6=\{A1, A3\}
\\
S_7=\{A1, B1\}
\\
S_8=\{A3, B1\}
\\
S_9=\{C3\}$$

See what we've done here. $A3$ is no longer in $S_1$, because we cannot have $t_1=A3$ and $t_4=B3$, since they are three apart and have the same number with consecutive letters. For the same reason, $A3$ is no longer in $S_7$. $B_1$ has been removed from $S_6$, since it's in the same group of three as $B3$ and you can't have two elements of the same letter in a group of three. Since the only other $C$ elements in the middle group of three were in $S_4$, our $C$ element now *must* be $C2$ from $S_5$, and thus, it cannot be in $S_1$. Since now there are only $A$ elemnts in $S_1$, the only legal element in $S_2$ is $C1$, which, in turn, is removed from $S_9$. $C3$ is then removed from $S_8$, and as the only $A2$ is in $S_1$, $A1$ is removed.

We now have something like this:

> $T=\{A2, C1, B2, B3, C2, ??, ??, ??, C3\}$

Truthfully, the values of the three missing elements don't even matter, because look at what we have: we've shown that $t_2$ must be $C1$, and $t_5$ must be $C2$. We have two elements that are *forced* to be three apart with the same letter and adjacent numbers. QED.